# CoreData relationships vs. attributes

Tags: ios, core-data

In an app where I use CoreData, I would to make two entities that are related to each other; let's say `List` and `Item` and each `List` will have many `Item`s. Now I would like to know which is better, to use a Relationship, one-to-many, or a Parent attribute in the `Item` entity. For Example, if I will use Relationships, I will relate each `Item` to its parent `List`. On the other hand, if I use an attribute, I'll save the `List`'s ID in the attribute.

Which will be the better approach to use, Relationships or Attributes, and what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use relationships. This results in scalable, usable, and well-performing code.

The concept of the parent entities is actually quite different. It is meant for entities that share the same basic attributes and maybe differ only slightly with additional attributes. For example, say, `Animal` could be the parent entity, and `Bird`, `Mammal` could be child entities. They would have common fields, but maybe some different ones as well.

The biggest drawback of parent entities is that all the child entities are going to be stored *in the same SQLite table* which will eventually affect performance.

Comment: Is it not default that the child entities will be stored in the same SQLite table even when using relationships? I mean if I'll be creating more than one child entity, they will be each in a different table (i.e. a table for each entity that contains all its data) and each is connected to its parent entity by a relationship. In this case it will not matter whether I use a relationship or an attribute that stores the ID. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: Yes, wrong. You are confusing parent and child entities with ordinary entities linked by relationships. (These can form a hierarchical, "parent-child-like" structure or not.) Perhaps you also confoun the database (essentially a file) and the tables (structural element in this file).